# Particle swarm optimization pbest and gbest

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, mathematical-optimization

can update particles velocity and position and then find the pbest and gbest? or pbest and gbest must be found first? what pbest and gbest in PSO?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your question, the answer is yes. As we know, the PSO's main equations are:

[image: eq]

[image: eq2]

Where x and v are the position and velocity, w, c1 and c2 are constants and r1 and r2 two random numbers. In summary, the PSO algorithm flows like that:

1. Start your population
2. Set the constants (w, c1 and c2)
3. Check stop criterion or convergence
4. Get the random numbers r1 and r2
5. Update Gbest and Pbest
6. Update v and x
7. Return to 3

The Pbest stores the best position, so far, for particle k and Gbest stores the best position for all particles. It's used to make all particles points to the global max/min. It's also affected by the topology:

[image]

If you use a global topology, it's easier to get stuck in a local min/max. On the other hand, your algorithm may converge faster. So, this depends on your problem and you need to test.

Comment: So first the pbest and gbest must be updated and based on that velocity and position can be updated. we can not update particle position and velocity if we havent set the initial pbest and gbest first. am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're. You need to ser the Gbest and Pbest first. Nonetheless, observe the first time you run the algorithm loop, all particles will get random positions in the search space. So, the first Pbest will be the particle itself and first Gbest will be one of the random particles, according to your fitness function.